# onchange event is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have properly add on change event within the select box but it is not working.Any lead would be appreciated.Thanks in advance

```
HTML

[<select  id="notifyBy" ng-change="selectchange()" style="border:none" class="formtext1" ng-model="selectvalue"  >
                            <option value="1">E-mail, telephone, etc.</option>
                            <option>Telephone No:</option>
                            <option>Telephone No:</option>
                            <option>Telephone No:</option>
                            <option>Telephone No:</option>
                        </select>][1]

controller

angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

[.controller('AppCtrl',\['$scope',function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout,$location,$ionicPopover,$http,$ionicNativeTransitions) {

$scope.selectchange = function() {
       alert("enterd");
      }][1]
}])
```

Comment: Check your developer tools console tab for identifying the issue. I think you might get a clue from there.

Comment: Your code seems fine. I guess you have added the block of code which you have posted in the same controller "starter.controllers"

Comment: I have created separate controller for this but still it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing value for options

```
<option value="2">Telephone No:</option>
```

**Details**

```
<option value="1">E-mail, telephone, etc.</option>
<option >Telephone No:</option> <!--Added value attribute here -->
<option >Telephone No:</option> <!--Added value attribute here -->
```

Here the problem is

1. When you change the value to option 2 (Telephone No:) from option1(E-mail, telephone, etc.), it triggers the onchange event
2. When you change the value to option 3 (Telephone No:) from option 2(Telephone No:), it will not triggers the onchange event because there is no change in value

**Solution**

So you should have the different values for all.

Solution 1:

```
<option value="2">Telephone No:</option> <!--Added value attribute here -->
<option value="3">Telephone No:</option> <!--Added value attribute here -->
```

Solution 2 :

```
<option>Telephone No:1</option> <!--Added value attribute here -->
<option>Telephone No:2</option> <!--Added value attribute here -->
```

```js
angular.module('starter', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $location, $ionicPopover, $http, $ionicNativeTransitions) {

    $scope.selectchange = function() {
      alert("enterd");
    }
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <select id="notifyBy" ng-change="selectchange()" style="border:none" class="formtext1" ng-model="selectvalue">
    <option value="1">E-mail, telephone, etc.</option>
    <option value="2">Telephone No:</option> <!--Added value attribute here -->
    <option value="3">Telephone No:</option> <!--Added value attribute here -->
    <option value="4">Telephone No:</option>
    <option value="5">Telephone No:</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: The code without the values assigned will still trigger a change. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/2yt04ztr/11/

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren Please have a look at my updated answer

Comment: The edit makes it a lot more clear for the OP to understand what the problem is, nice. :)

Comment: I have added values to each option and still it is not working .

Comment: @ShristiS.Chavhan What is not working? Are you able to trigger ng-change for 1st option?

Comment: @NagaveerGowda No .It is not going into the function itself.

Comment: @ShristiS.Chavhan Create the fiddle link and share. It is difficult to give resolution without having complete code

Comment: Main problem is that i can't able to go in controller itself.

Comment: @ShristiS.Chavhan You have to add all dependencies. Dependencies are missing in your application

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because you are selecting the same value again and again.

Try to add a value with each option.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);
app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.selectchange = function() {
       alert("enterd");
      }
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body ng-controller="dobController">
  <select id="notifyBy" ng-change="selectchange()" style="border:none" class="formtext1" ng-model="selectvalue">
    <option value="1">E-mail, telephone, etc.</option>
    <option value="2">Telephone No:</option>
    <option value="3">Telephone No:</option>
    <option value="4">Telephone No:</option>
    <option value="5">Telephone No:</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code without the values assigned will still trigger a change. Proof: jsfiddle.net/2yt04ztr/11

Comment: I have changed the option value and still it is not working.

Comment: @ShristiS.Chavhan check the demo

Comment: Yeah i have checked the demo and done in the same way .Still  it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Angular seems to be difficult hence few time we make mistakes from out end, here couple of thing i saw not complete.

1. Add "ng-app" or bootstrap application to use angular features.
2. Also, I could not see ng-controller anywhere in html code.
3. Injection should be done correctly. Then one which appear with in function parenthesis are alias name to actual service.

Great so **here you go:**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.selectchange = function() {
      alert("enterd");
    }
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document, ['starter.controllers']);
```

**JSFiddle link**: https://jsfiddle.net/Ashokkumargupta/8a7zxdq4/1/

Cheers,
Ashok

Comment: I have added ng-app and ng-controller and function name is alias with the actual service name and still it is not working :(

Comment: Does JSfiddle link helped you?

Comment: No.Actually problem is that  i am not able to access the controller.and now error coming is "[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'starter.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

Comment: Please send the screenshot and the code. I will look into it in free time.

Comment: Thank u It's working now.Problem was with controller . :)